# Android: How to change the color of the dateselector in Datepicker widget?

Tags: android, colors, datepicker, calendar, selector

this is my first time posting a question.

I've successfully implemented a Datepicker in my app (targeting only SDK 21 and above). I also want to style my Datepicker to blend with the rest of the app. This is what I have:

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primDark</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/prim</item>
    <item name="android:calendarTextColor">@color/primDark</item>
    <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/primDark</item>
    <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
</style>
```

I can't find the attribute to change the color of the day selector in the calendar. No attribute listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) does that. However I was able to change the color of the year selector (see right side of the screenshot) with the attribute "yearListSelectorColor". How can I color the corresponding selector and selected text color on the left side?

To clarify, this is what my Datepicker looks like: [Screenshots](http://abload.de/img/s38wudd.png)

So if someone knows how to get rid of that standard teal color, please tell me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay I think I got it.

I tried desperately to find an attribute in MyDatePickerStyle. The solution came to my mind when I rethought the whole inheritance hierarchy. I just had to add the colorAccent to the MyDatePickerDialogTheme.

```
<style name="MyDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!-- this is new -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primDark</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/prim</item>
    <item name="android:calendarTextColor">@color/primDark</item>
    <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/primDark</item>
    <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
    <item name="android:minDate">01/01/2000</item>
</style>
```

Somehow I thought every theme gets the primary colors from the AppTheme automatically.

So hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, date selector didn't changed

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the selector circle in DatePicker, use `android:colorControlActivated` attribute in your theme.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22270297)

Comment: @meJustAndrew Thanks a lot for your feedback. Did I fix it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try 3 steps:

- 1: Go to the activity manifest and check the `android:theme` style.

[image]

- 2: Go to the styles.xml file, Find the `android:theme` from manifest.

[image]

- 3: Add new item:android -> colorAccent and colorControlActivated

[image]