# Change the color of selected date only in date picker android

Tags: android, android-styles, android-datepicker

[image]

I am using date picker and I need to style it with different colors. All things are working fine except the selected date color. The thing is selected date color takes "android:textColorPrimaryInverse" as default which in my case is red , background of the dialog is white and the "android:colorControlHighlight" and "android:colorControlActivated" is also red.

This means the selected text color doesn't show.I need that to be shown as white but the issue is if I change"android:textColorPrimaryInverse" to white my title won't appear as the background is white.

here is my style file :

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePickerStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/red</item>
    </style>
```

and this is how I show my dialog

```
 new DatePickerDialog(mActivity, R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }, 2015, 02, 26).show();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511743/android-how-to-change-the-color-of-the-dateselector-in-datepicker-widget

Answer (score 11):

Use;

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/red</item>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try below code

```
 <style name="CustomDatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/CustomDatePickerStyle</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/prim</item>
        <item name="android:calendarTextColor">@color/primDark</item>
        <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/primDark</item>
        <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If using `MaterialDatePicker` this example could be helpful:

```
<style name="DefaultDatePickerTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/DefaultCalendarStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DefaultDatePickerButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DefaultDatePickerButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DefaultDatePickerButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/date_picker_cta_text</item>
</style>

<style name="DefaultCalendarStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="daySelectedStyle">@style/DefaultDaySelectedStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DefaultDaySelectedStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day.Selected">
    <item name="itemFillColor">@color/blue_violet</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to deal with in your style is 'colorControlActivated' and 'selectableItemBackgroundBorderless' . Check the code snippet below:

```
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#@color/Green</item>
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">@color/LightPink</item>
```

Current date will be 'Green' and selected date will have a 'LightPink' boardering background

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/red</item>
```

This worked for me.