# How can I paint the days of a Calendar using a DatePicker?

Tags: java, android-studio, datepicker, calendar, datepickerdialog

I need i way to change the color of the days of the Calendar, please help i am new with this theme or maybe someone knows how the calendar paint the current day??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the color of selected date only in date picker android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512895/change-the-color-of-selected-date-only-in-date-picker-android)

Comment: The DatePickerDialog doesn't have a method for paint the days of the calendar ??